# Login Android App using JSON

Tags: android

I am working on an android application in which the data is fetched through JSONs using the web-service. Following is the JSON string that i am using to login the app.The parameters,wsfunction,syntax all are checked and found to be correct.

**MainActivity.java**

```
String loginjson = "{\"userDetails\":[{\"username\":"
       +"\""
+username.getText().toString().trim()
+"\",\"password\":"
+"\""
+password.getText().toString()
+"\",\"ipaddress\":"
+"\""
+Constants.ipaddress
+"\",\"lastaccess\":\"0\"}],\"wsfunction\":\"user_authentication\"}";

Constants.sercall.servercall(loginjson);
```

Also here is code in which logic for the request and response to and from the server is written.

**servercalls.java**

```
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import android.util.Log;
public class Servercalls {

        public String response_str="";
        public HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        public HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url); //PHP webservice url

        public void servercall(String jsonstring){
         try {
                 Log.d("Request to server",jsonstring);  
                JSONArray postjson=new JSONArray();
                    postjson.put(jsonstring);
                    httppost.setHeader("json",jsonstring);
                     httppost.getParams().setParameter("jsonpost",postjson);
                HttpResponse response;
                response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                   if(response != null){
                InputStream is = response.getEntity().getContent();
                     BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
                     String line="";
                          while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                                         response_str=line;
                                Log.e("Response from server",response_str);  
                           }         
                        }
                        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        Log.e("cpexception", "Error in client protocol" + e.toString());
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                        Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection "+ e.toString());
                                }
         }

}
```

It is giving output as:

{"error":1,"msg":"No service Specified"}

plz help me to get proper response from server....

Comment: Where do you set the URL to server? :P

Comment: Also, you should probably take a look at JSONObject and JSONArray in order to convert them to strings, a much better approach, available since API 1.

Comment: The output looks like a valid response from the backend service, indicating that your request is missing some input parameter?

Comment: But I have tested this JSON string on php testsevice for response for the same url. It is giving proper response there but not through android code.